# Understanding Optional<T>.map()

Tags: java, java-8, spring-data-jpa

Reviewing an example use of `Optional` where the optional is first loaded with a database call and then mapped to a Spring security `UserDetails` instance.  The code looks like this:

```
Optional<User> user = userRepository.findByName(username);
user.orElseThrow(()-> new UsernameNotFoundException("Ahhh Shuckkkks!!!");
return user.map(CustomUserDetails::new).get();
```

In the last line would that call equal `return new CustomUserDetails(user.get())`.

Also anyone know if there's an even shorter more fluid way to write the above example?

Comment: `return new CustomUserDetails(userRepository.findByName(username).orElseThrow(()-> new UsernameNotFoundException("Ahhh Shuckkkks!!!")));` ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, that would be equivalent. But the code should rather be written as

```
return userRepository.findByName(username)
    .map(CustomUserDetails::new)
    .orElseThrow(()-> new UsernameNotFoundException("Ahhh Shuckkkks!!!"));
```

That avoids a useless variable, isolates the exceptional case at the end, and avoids the nasty call to `get()`, which is only guaranteed to work fine here because you have called `orElseThrow()` before.